# setEnabled(false) not hiding TextView

Tags: android, textview, visible

So I'm following an Android tutorial and came across an issue. The video maker uses `setEnabled(false)` to hide a `TextView` until the user clicks a certain button. However, when I tried the same code, the `TextView` was on the screen before the user clicked the button. I've been trying to work out why for an hour, but to no avail. Below is a link to the video and a picture of my relevant code, XML code, and screen display.

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NGRV2qY9ZiU  Talks about setEnabled at 16:35

[image: main code]

[image: XML]

[image: screen display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when I tried the same code, the TextView was on the screen before the user clicked the button.

`setEnabled(false)` won't actually hide the TextView. To do that you need to do

```
result.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

When you are ready to make it visible (instead of `setEnabled(true)`):

```
result.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I don't believe the vid maker used those though, and his TextView was hidden. Was the method updated or changed recently?

Comment: `setEnabled` should only disable the TextView from being clickable.

Comment: I took a look at his video, and his code is wrong. The only reason the TextView is hidden initially is not because of `setEnabled(false)`, but because there is no text assigned to it. He could remove the `setEnabled(false)` and `setEnabled(true)` lines and the code would behave the same way. Once he assigns the `TextView` some text it becomes visible.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
result.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

instead.

## Edit:

note that:

```
    result.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

would also hide the view but it would still be clickable.

Comment: I did look into those but I want to know why `setEnabled` worked for the vid maker but not me

Comment: Note this is incorrect. When it's invisible the button is still clickable. It needs to be `View.GONE`

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method. It will hide the element from the view.

```
result.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```